# Dependency from Module to EAR

Tags: jboss

Good Day....

We are working on a project to migratate J2EE application from WAS 8.5 to JBOSS EAP 7.0 and we are new to JBOSS.

Application bundle  with:
1) EAR (WAR and EJB)
2) Application Utility Jars and Persistence jars (Entity classes)
3)Third party jar like log4j2.5,Jackson,hibernate,

We created folder named sharedLib and maintained sharedLib/main/module.xml

We moved all our  Application Utility Jars, Persistence jars, and  Third party jar to shardLib Module.

```
    <resource-root path="../SEC_BatchService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_DepartmentService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_LoginService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_MenuService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_ProcessesService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_SessionMaintenanceService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_SessionService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SecurityInterfaceServices_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_UserAuthoriser_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_UserMaintenanceService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SEC_UserRole_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../SystemUtility_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../WorkFlow_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../Application_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../BootStrapService_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../Intergration_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../Logger_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="../Persistence_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/Logger_Contract-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/btf-1.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.json-1.0.13.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/commons-httpclient-3.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/cors-filter-2.5.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/disruptor-3.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/guava-19.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/jackson-annotations-2.7.3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/jackson-core-2.7.3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="/apps/SGDEV/config/SEC/product/thirdParty/jackson-coreutils-1.8.jar"/>

    And   APP_EAR/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
              Manifest-Version: 1.0
              Dependencies: sharedLib
```

We are not facing any issue while invoking sharedLib Module files from EAR. But files which is resides in sharedLib not able to access EJB jar of EAR.

Example WAR -----> EJB--> sharedLib (Module) Fine
               WAR -----> EJB1--> sharedLib ---> EJB2.jar Failed with NoClassDifferror.  (not able to access any class of EJB jar POJO classes.)

can we invoke EAR EJB Jar from  sharedLib (Isolated Module)

Error :

Flow : Rest Service ----> EJB.jar ---> EJB.jar --->   sharedLib ---> EJB

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scb/technical/bootstrap/process/SystemProperties                ----------------(POJO Class resides in EJB JAR) --------------
        at scb.technical.security.service.util.SecurityUtility.convertDateToUserTZ(SecurityUtility.java:257) ----------------------(POJO Class resides in sharedLib Module)----------------------
        at scb.technical.security.service.LoginServiceBean.validateLogin(LoginServiceBean.java:161) ------------------------(SessionBean  resides in EJB JAR)----------------------------
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
        ... 212 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scb.technical.bootstrap.process.SystemProperties from [Module "sharedLib:main" from local module loader @66133adc (finder: local module finder @7bfcd12c (roots: /jboss/eap/7.0/jboss-eap/modules,/jboss/eap/7.0/jboss-eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.6.CP,/jboss/eap/7.0/jboss-eap/modules/system/layers/base))]

Server : JBOSS EAP 7.0

Thanks
Viswa..

Comment: If I have understand correctly you want a static (means in the modules folder) to have a dependency in your dynamic application module. I don't think it is a good idea. But anyway have you tried to declared the EJB2.jar as an explicit dependency in the manifest of the static  module deployed?

Comment: Thanks loannis.  i added below entry in jboss-deployment-structure.xml of static JAR Module:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.O3_APP_EAR.ear.BootStrapService.jar"/>
            <module name="deployment.BootStrapService.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Still same issue...Not sure how to link EJB jar to static module jars.

Comment: I am not sure either. But since these two are not decoupled, why not deployed in the same way? Static modules have the meaning that they are used so often you want them always deployed and they are undependable. A good example is a driver for MySQL where all of your deployments lie in this technology. But why do you want a module to be deployed in a static way since it depends in a dynamic deployed module?

Comment: Thanks loannis. Its was developed long back and working fine in WAS platform. Only we are facing this issue in JBOSS Environment. in WAS both PARENT and isolated shared library mananged by single class loader. Looks in JBOSS, there is no such class loader to load both Static and Dynamic classes under same class loader hierarchy.. Still we are find a way to make it work..

Comment: Its not technically possible to invoke deployment class files from static module class loader. Only reverse is possible. Thanks..